# Magento 2 - How to override footer phtml

Tags: magento2, footer

I want to customize my website footer. To do this I need to update footer, I don't want to customize vendor phtml as this is not recommended.

Current template is

```
vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\templates\html\footer.phtml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own `default.xml` file at `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<ThemeName>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="footer" template="html/footer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now your custom ***footer.phtml*** file is called.

Note : Template path should be ***`app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<ThemeName>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml`***

Comment: I followed these steps and flushed the cache and my custom footer file was not displaying. Could it have something to do with an installed theme?

Comment: Simple and clear answer, worked a treat, thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

When editing xml layout files, you will need to run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```